# Android: How to detect if a broadcaster application is deleted?

Tags: android, uninstallation, broadcast

I have 2 applications. One of them is doing broadcast custom strings continously and the other one is receiving. I have to be notified and delete some datas in the reciever application when the broadcaster application is deleted. Is there a method like onDelete() or something like that? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! There's an intent called [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) that you can listen for.

Add this inside `<application>` in your manifest: (don't forget to change the package name)

```
  <receiver android:name="com.arjnklc.receiverapp.UninstallReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/> 
        <data android:scheme="package" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Then you need to create the class mentioned above.

```
public class UninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart() == "com.arjnklc.broadcasterapp")
      cleanUpEverything();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you make logout requests to the remote server when you receive this intent? How much time you usually get to handle all needed requests?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure when you want to do but from what I understand, you want your second application to know when the first application is deleted?

If that's the case, do this:

In **AndroidManifest.xml**, you MUST have a new `BroadcastReceiver` because this receiver used a different data scheme:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".PackageReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED");

            String data = intent.getData().toString();
            // data string has the package name
            // if that is your package name, your first app was uninstalled
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure, it's a separate BroadcastReceiver. It can not be combined with any other Receiver or the other actions will stop working.

Hope this works.